# Update billing address in the checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2.4.3

I'm using **magento 2.4.3**, I have created a plugin that creates different shipping methods.

My issue is that one of the shipping methods is a pickup service, which I successfully changed the shipping address however I can't keep the billing address or update the billing address.

My question is: **How do I update the billing address in javascript?**

I know by default the billing address is set as the same as shipping address, how do I disable it?